# 英語が残っている: Human verification

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

[image: Human verification]

Answer (score 2):

keiminaの提案で「あなたがロボットでないことの証明」に更新済

現在の和訳は「人による検証」

これでよろしければ、適用します。

Comment: 「あなたがロボットでないことの証明」のほうがよいです。

Answer (score 0):

> 人間であることを証明してください

ちょっとアグレッシブでしょうか